# Nested dictionary to Dataframe in the most efficient way possible

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, optimization, nested

I have a nested dictionary like this one:

```
my_dict[user_profile][user_id][level] = [[9999, 'Heavy Purchaser', 340, 'Star_chest', 999, 1000],
   [9999, 'Heavy Purchaser', 340, 'Star_chest', 998, 5],
   [9999, 'Heavy Purchaser', 340, 'Star_chest', 3, 1],
   [9999, 'Heavy Purchaser', 340, 'Star_chest', 4, 1]]
```

Basically, per each user_profile, user_id I'm collecting the rewards received per level.
The number of lists contained in `dict[user_profile][user_id][level]` is variable and not fix.

A reward looks like this : `[9999, 'Heavy Purchaser', 340, 'Star_chest', 999, 1000]`

I want to create a DF of rewards using the most efficient and fastest solution.
In the end this is what I want:

```
 ID      user_profile     user_id  Chest_type  item_code  amount
9999  'Heavy Purchaser'  340       'Star_chest'  999      1000
9999  'Heavy Purchaser'  340       'Star_chest'  4        1
9999  'Heavy Purchaser'  340       'Star_chest'  3        1
```

I tried to append each single list using `df.loc[df.shape[0]] = list_with_rewards`, but it's taking too much time. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that you are starting with is *not* a nested dictionary, it is just a nested list.  You may want to consider transitioning to a nested dictionary that would seem to make more sense for the type of data you are gathering...  But that is another question.  :)

In `pandas`, generally the last thing you want to do is add to a data frame row by row, or anything row by row in general.  If you look through the dox for data frame, there are several ways to create from data, based on data structure or file type and data orientation.  Your data is a "list of lists" where each list can be interpreted as a "record" or one row in a  datframe or database.  So, you can just use the `from_records()` construct.  Behold:

```
In [7]: import pandas as pd

In [8]: data = [[9999, 'Heavy Purchaser', 340, 'Star_chest', 999, 1000],
   ...:    [9999, 'Heavy Purchaser', 340, 'Star_chest', 998, 5],
   ...:    [9999, 'Heavy Purchaser', 340, 'Star_chest', 3, 1],
   ...:    [9999, 'Heavy Purchaser', 340, 'Star_chest', 4, 1]]

In [9]: type(data)
Out[9]: list

In [10]: pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=['ID', 'user', 'user_id', 'chest', 'count', 'amount'])
Out[10]: 
     ID             user  user_id       chest  count  amount
0  9999  Heavy Purchaser      340  Star_chest    999    1000
1  9999  Heavy Purchaser      340  Star_chest    998       5
2  9999  Heavy Purchaser      340  Star_chest      3       1
3  9999  Heavy Purchaser      340  Star_chest      4       1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I just learned the difference between a nested list and a dictionary! For the future, do you suggest creating a nested dictionary? Because I'm randomly sampling the opening of a ''chest'' with some items for each user id of a given profile; I created them so that they return me an actual record of my DB. Do you think that if I create a nested dictionary instead of a list it would be faster?

Comment: It completed depends on context of how you create the data, the structure of the data, and how you will use/poll the data.  There are many entry level tutorials on the advantages of different data structures, which is well beyond the scope of a SO question.  You might start at the link below, which covers dictionaries and lists and some of the benefits.  To your question...  once the data is built as above, turning it into a DF is about the same speed, no matter the format.  https://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python/